# Ajax code is not working im using it with jsp

Tags: javascript, ajax, eclipse, jsp

i dont know whats wrong with my code i am trying to run function where when i type username then it get detected weather it is already present in database or not but its not working.
i am getting username at console after firing query but my span is not working.

this is my sign up page with ajax

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/signup-style.css">
<title>Signup</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/home-style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>


</head>
<body>


    <!--navbar  -->
    <%-- <%@include file="header.jsp"%> --%>

    <br>
    <div class="topnav sticky">

        <center>
            <h2>Shoppers</h2>
        </center>

        <a href="index.jsp">Home<i class="fa fa-institution"></i></a> <a
            href="signup.jsp">Register<i class='fas fa-user-alt'></i></a> <a
            href="login.jsp">Login <i class="fa fa-address-book"></i></a>
    </div>
    </div>




    <div id='container'>
        <div class='signup'>
            <form action="signupAction.jsp" method="post">
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name" required>
                <span id="available"></span>
                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email" required>
                <input type="number" name="mobileNumber"
                    placeholder="Enter Mobile Number" required> <select
                    name="securityQuestion" required>

                    <option value="What was your first car?">What was your
                        first car?</option>
                    <option value="What's your favourite sports?">What's your
                        favourite sports?</option>
                    <option value="What's your favourite food?">What's your
                        favourite food?</option>
                    <option value="What's your favourite colour?">What's your
                        favourite colour?</option>
                </select> <input type="text" name="answer" placeholder="Enter Your answer"
                    required> <input type="password" name="password"
                    placeholder="Enter Password" required>
                    <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Enter Address" required>
                    <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="Enter City" required>
                    <input type="text" name="state" placeholder="Enter State" required>
                    <input type="text" name="country" placeholder="Enter Country" required>
                    

                <!-- <input type="submit" value="signup"> -->

                <button type="submit" class="submitBtn">Register</button>


            </form>

            <h2>
                <a href="login.jsp">Login</a>
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div class='whysign'>
            <%
            String msg = request.getParameter("msg");
            if ("valid".equals(msg)) {
            %>
            <!-- <h1>Successfuly Registered</h1> -->
            <div class="alert alert-success">
                <strong>Success!</strong> Registered Successfully
            </div>
            <%
            }
            %>

            <%
            if ("invalid".equals(msg)) {
            %>
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <strong>Registered Failed</strong> Something went wrong Please try
                again
            </div>
            <%
            }
            %>

            <h2>Shoppers</h2>
            <p>Shoppers is the application that allows the users to shop
                online without going to the shops to buy them.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.0/sweetalert.min.js">
        
    </script>

    <script src="js/button.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
    <script
        src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <!--AJAX  -->
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        console.log("name clicked");
        
        $("#name").blur(function(){
            
            console.log("inside blur function");
            
            var name= $("#name").val();
            
            console.log(""+name);
            if(name.length>=3)
                {
                $.ajax({
                    url:"checkname.jsp",
                    type:"post",
                    data:"name="+name,
                    dataType:"text",
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                        $("available").html(data)
        
                    }       
                });
                
                }
            else
                {
                   $("#available").html(" ");
                
                }
            
        });
    });
    
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my checkname.jsp

```
<%@page import="com.onlineshopingproject.helper.connectionprovider"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>

<%
System.out.println("Inside checkname");
if (request.getParameter("name") != null) {
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    try {
        Connection con = connectionprovider.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from users where name=? ");
        ps.setString(1, name);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        
        if (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println("inside rs");
            
%>
<% 
System.out.println(rs.getString("name"));
%>

<span class="text-danger">Sorry name Already Exists </span>

<%
} else {
%>
<span class="text-success">User name Available</span>
<%
}
        con.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println(e);
}

}
%>
```

i am not getting span alert box which i have mentioned i dont know why please help.

Comment: `$("available").html(data)` in one place `$("#available").html(" ");` in the other ... there's a difference

Comment: please correct me if i am wrong i am not understanding what i am doing wrong

Comment: `$("available")` ... looks for a html tag named `available` .... `$("#available")` looks for a tag with an id `available` ... which one do you have in your HTML? a `<available>` or a `<span id="available">` ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake problem has been solved now